# How to use a variable for document.form_name.element_name

Tags: javascript, variables

Simple question. Is it possible to replace the following code:

```
document.form_name.element_name
```

with

```
document.form_name.<array[index].value>
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.form_name[array[index].value];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_element = "username";
document.form_name[my_element];
```

and

```
var fields = [ "username", "realname" ];
document.form_name[fields[0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `<array[index].value>` has "element_name" in it, you can do the following:

```
document.form_name[array[index].value]
```